# Resize table according to image

Tags: html, css

I am having a background image inside a div. I chose a background image since I want a search bar to be placed over it. Anyways, under the background image, that acts as a header, I placed a table. The header resizes according to the screen width. The table width does the same. However, the distance between header and table increases when the screen size decreases.
Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be fixed?
Here is my HTML

```
    <div class= "resize">
    </div>
<div class="table-container">
<h3>Latest Job Postings</h3>
<table class = "table table-striped table-bordered table-centered">
  <tr>
    <th class="description">Description</th>
    <th class="location">Location</th>
  </tr>
  <td>[description]</td>
  <td>[Location]</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

My CSS
/*resize container */
  .resize{
    background-image: url("header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 350px;   
}

/* table */
.table-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}


th.description {
  width: 80%;
}

th.location {
  width: 10%;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're describing. You're getting a larger vertical gap between `<div class= "resize"></div>` and `<div class="table-container">...</div>`?

Comment: Yes, so there is a vertical gab between the image and the table when I resize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

**Demo**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbFbj/)

The problem is that you have set the `background-size:100%` for the header section, this will cause **both** the width and the height of the background image to resize according to width .

So, when you resize the window, the width of the background image changes and the height also changes accordingly. and since the container has a fixed height, when the height of the background image decreases, it will create a gap below it.

What I did is to change the background-size property to be like this

```
background-size: 100% 350px;
```

This will make the height of the background image constant and the width will respond to the container width changes.

Comment: Okay this works for me. However, I would like the image height to change according to the screen size. Is there a way that the height of the image continues to change while the distance between image and table stays the same?

Comment: @EternalHour if I remove the height, the gap between image and table increases again when resizing the screen